# Configure local SVN

Tags: linux, apache, svn, version-control

I have installed an SVN Repository on my server. I always used to work in local, but now I need to checkout the repository inside the server.

well, this are the configurations:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /srv/svn/xxx
    AuthName "XXX Repository"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /srv/svn/xxx/.svn.passwd
    Require valid-user
    #SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

I have done an `svn checkout http://www.example.com/svn mydir/`

and if I do an SVN update, everything works good but if I do an svn commit, it says:

```
svn: E160013: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E160013: '/svn/!svn/me' path not found
```

and I can solve this problem putting above the configuration this line:

```
alias /svn /srv/svn/tomsnetwork.it
```

but if I do this, `svn update¡ doesn't work anymore (it says:

```
Redirecting to URL 'http://www.example.com/svn':
Redirecting to URL 'http://www.example.com/svn':
svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for URL 'http://www.example.com/svn'
```

Answer (score 0):

How does your update and commit commands look like?

Maybe you should give the [SCM-Manager](http://www.scm-manager.org) a try. It is a open source tool where you can very easy manage your subversion repositories over a simple GUI. No editing of configuration files is needed. Just download and start the standalone version. No additional software must be installed and it's functionality can easily extended by plugins. It can also manage git and mercurial repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the alias.

Since `svn co` worked, it looks like everything is setup correctly. Even `svn up` worked.

If the problem was your authorization file, the checkout wouldn't have worked.

The problem might be due to directory permissions. Who *owns* the directory tree `/srv/svn/xxx`? I have a feeling that you own it because you're the one who created the directory. Unfortunately, Apache httpd, depending upon the OS, is under a user like `http`, `httpd`, `apache`, `wwwrun`, or a variety of different users. See which user owns the `httpd` process, and make sure that the entire repository directory tree is owned by that user.

This command will change the owner and group of your repository directory to the correct owner assuming the process user running `httpd` is `httpd`:

```
$ sudo chown -R httpd:httpd /srv/svn/xxx
```

Also, once this is done, make sure that the permissions on all files and directories is read/writable to this user (and this user only):

```
$ sudo chmod -R u+a /srv/svn/xxx
```

Comment: well, this dir is owned by a user: if I change the owner to www-data, i can commit from the server, but I can't commit from my computer :/

Comment: What is _a user_? Is it the user running `httpd`? Did you change all ***files*** and ***directories*** in your repository directory to be owned by that user? Make sure directories have the execute permission bit set too. Is this http server only used for Subversion, or is this being used for other webpages too?

Comment: - A _user_ is a linux user that i can use to access to the server via ssh
- No, is a normal user
- Yes, i changed all files
- What is the chmod command that i have to use?
- It's used also for other webpages

Comment: @OscarFanelli You're accessing the repo via `http` and `svn+ssh`? That can be very problematic. Ssh creates files under the user who ran the `svn+ssh` while Apache httpd may refuse to read or write files that aren't owned by the user running httpd no matter what the permissions are. You can run `svn://` and `http://` access simultaneously, without problems, but adding ssh to the mix can cause the issues you're seeing.

Comment: I think this is the problem. With one user i access via http, with another one I access via `file:///`

Maybe i have to access only via `svn://`... where can I find the apache configuration for a `svn://`? Thanks

Comment: @OscarFanelli There's no Apache configuration for `svn://`, you simply use `svnserve` and you can use it at the same time as `httpd`. The big problem may be authorization coordination between `httpd` and `svnserve`. It's possible to keep the authorization between the two in sync, but it isn't easy.

Comment: @OscarFanelli Be careful when you use another protocol with `httpd` because of permission issues. I too use `file:///` when I'm logged onto the server because it's fast. If you use [Fisheye](https://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/overview) or [viewvc](http://www.viewvc.org), it is recommended (and may even be required) to use `file:///` for those programs to access the repository. ***However***, if you use `file:///`, you shouldn't commit any changes to the repository simply because it could create or modify files in such a way that your `httpd` server won't be able to access them.